# How Do I Determine the Criteria for Allocating Pages to the Client Project in ASP.NET Core Blazor United .NET 8?

Tags: blazor

Blazor United in .NET 8 creates two projects,

[image]

1. "**BlazorApp1**" project
2. "**BlazorApp1.Client**" project.

I understood that, "BlazorApp1" is designated for Static Server and WebSocket pages, I cannot or I should not use @rendermode InteractiveWebAssembly or @rendermode InteractiveAuto in the "BlazorApp1" project.

Then, I assumed that, in the "BlazorApp1.Client" project, I should or I can use pages with attribute only @rendermode InteractiveWebAssembly. But, surprisingly I see that, I can use @rendermode InteractiveServer in a page in the "BlazorApp1.Client". And it works without any error. In fact, I can use regular Statis Server pages in that "BlazorApp1.Client" project.

This discovery leads me to question the necessity of distributing pages between two projects.

**If "BlazorApp1.Client" supports all render modes specially InteractiveServer, is there a compelling reason not to consolidate all pages there for organizational simplicity?**

I really hate the idea to distribute my pages between two projects, and I discovered that, I do not need to distribute my pages between two projects, I can rather have all of pages into the "BlazorApp1.Client" project where I can have different render modes including InteractiveServer. Then why should I bother hosting some InteractiveServer pages into the BlazorApp1 page? What is the catch here?

Comment: IP in the client....

Answer (score 1):

The template builds two deployment projects:

1. *Server* [the poject with the same name as the solution].  It uses the Web Sdk [`<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">`] and builds a `WebApplication` in Program [`var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);`].
2. *Client*.  It uses the BlazorWebAssembly Sdk [`Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.BlazorWebAssembly"`] and builds a `WebAssemblyHost` in Program [`var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);`].

*Server* has a dependancy on *Client*, so has access to all the public objects in the *Client* assembly.  *Client* obviously can't have a dependancy on *Server*.  Even if it could, it would not compile because of library imcompatibilities.

The *Server* project has access to all the components in *Client*, but *Client* can't see components in *Server*.  Many programmers move components into one or more Razor Class Libraries.  These can be referenced by both projects.  My deploymnent projects contain no components: everything is in libraries.

When configuring the deployment projects and `Router` you need to provide additional information on where to find routable components [pages].

In the Server project you will see this defined:

```cs
app.MapRazorComponents<App>()
    .AddInteractiveServerRenderMode()
    .AddInteractiveWebAssemblyRenderMode()
    .AddAdditionalAssemblies(typeof(Counter).Assembly);
```

`MapRazorComponents` tells the Razor component mapper to map any routable components in the project assembly as endpoints to the Http request pipeline.  `AddAdditionalAssemblies` tells it also add any routable components it finds in the `Counter` assembly [the Client Assembly].

In `Routes.razor` you will find this defined:

```cs
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly" AdditionalAssemblies="new[] { typeof(Client._Imports).Assembly }">
```

This tells the Blazor router to also add any routable components it finds in the `Counter` assembly [the Client Assembly] to it's route table.

If you want Razor or the Blazor router to fund routable compomnents in a Razor class library, you need to add that class library to the `AdditionalAssemblies` in the two places.

### Added Information

1. The client project doesn't support all modes - It can't render a page in Active SSR mode.  But it can be referenced by other projects and those project can use it's objects, including components.  How a component is rendered depends on a matrix based on it's own render mode and that of it's parent.
2. Why are the components distributed as they are?  Because the MS team responsible for the Template decided they wanted to do it that way.

.

Comment: Ok, you explained the infrastructure which is clear, but, my question was not how things are working, rather, my question was that, if "*.Client" project supports all render modes (where the server project does not), then what is the reason behind distributing pages between these two projects, rather why dont we place all of our pages in the single client project as I can have mix of render modes in client projects which is apparently working.

Comment: See additional Information in my answer.

Comment: As you said, "The client project doesn't support all modes - It can't render a page in Active SSR mode." - if this were true then I already got my answer, but last time I tested, I found that, the client project supports all modes including SSR. My questions was basically that, what could be a reason to put some pages in the Non Client project if Client project can host all types of render modes. I mean, keeping all pages in the same project really simplifies the organization of pages.

Comment: You are missing some vital knowledge: what a component really is and what setting the render node actually does.  A component is just a compiled class.   Adding the `@rendermode InteractiveServer` directive to the top of a Razor file tells the Razor compiler [which turns a Razor file into a C# class] to add a special RenderMode Attribute to the class.  Nothing more.  What the runtime does with that attribute is up to the runtime.  I think the WebAssembly executable will ignore it, but I haven't got that far in my investigations into what I call Auto mongrel mode does!

Comment: On organising components, you will find that in anything but a small project, organising generic components that you will use across projects and specific components that are application specific into separate class libraries is normal practice.

Comment: I totally understand what an attribute is and how it is applied.  
However, it seems you may not have fully explored the Blazor United project yet. In my tests, the 'interactive' attribute in the Client project dictates whether components render via SignalR or WebAssembly. Initially, I assumed the Client project was exclusive to WebAssembly components, but surprisingly I discovered that it also supports SignalR. This raises the question: why wouldn't one host a SignalR component in the Client project? What will be the catch if I do so?

Comment: Just to be clear here, which template and what Interactive render mode and Interactivity location options did you use?  We're all still discovering new things about Blazor 8!  It's hard to evaluate someone's knowledge level from a few comments.

Comment: In `InteractiveServer` mode, the DotNet Core SPA session - the Renderer [and components], DI Services etc run in a Hub Session on the Server.   There's no WebAssembly [unless things have changed since Net7 and I've missed it] involved.  It's all JS running the client side of the SignalR session receiving and applying DOM updates from the Hub session and sending DOM events.  Create a Scoped Service with an Id.  Inject it it into pages rendered in different modes and check the ID.  You will need to register it in both the Server and Client Applications.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think client support all render mode. When set to InteractiveServer. The server project will detect and "borrow" the pages from client project.
[image]
So it is still necessary to have 2 projects. When use websocket, pages are actually in server project.  When use webassembly, pages are in client projects. But you don't have to write these pages twice.

Comment: You said "I don't think client support all render mode.", actually it does and it has to. Why? Because, Client project supports InteractiveAuto render mode, which is essentially a mix of web socket and web asm. And thats why looks like Client project supports all render modes. I have already tested and found that my assumption is true.

Comment: @EmranHussain In client project, if use `InteractiveServer` , the page will compiled to server project.  If use `InteractiveAuto`  the page will compiled to both server and client projects.  So I said "client project not really support websocket mode etc".  It is just a trick. Put `InteractiveServer` makes the pages belongs to serverproject actually.

Comment: My question was basically about high level decision about placing pages between projects. I am not concerned which page compiles to what, I am saying if I place a Page with InteractiveServer render mode in the client project and if that compiles successfully, then, there is no reason to put that same page the Non Client project, right? Are there? I wanted to keep all pages in the same project so that I can have a good organization of pages.

Comment: @QiangFu is incorrect in his assertion that "if use InteractiveServer , the page will compiled to server project".  The component will be compiled into whatever project it resides in.  If it's in the Client project, the it's compiled into the Client project xxx.Client.dll.  Setting the Render mode just applies a `RenderModeAttribute` to the generated component class.

Comment: @EmranHussain Yes, for this question, you could put all pages in client project. I also put all pages in the client projects.  And I put controllers/apis in the server project.

Comment: @QiangFu Thank you, for confirmation. To me, Microsoft opted a very ugly and painful design by splitting blazor app into 2 projects with confusion, as if Client project is only for web assembly, but, truly that is not. MAUI app's great strength is that it is a single project, no more Android, iOS specific separate projects. They could do better for Blazor, where in Blazor the separate Client project is there only for creating confusion (my rant). Nevertheless, the CSS intellisence does not work in the Client Project, so it is not very fun to use Client project for all pages at the same time.

Comment: @EmranHussain Yes, the design is confused. Switching authentication between 2 modes also confused me.